# G suite admin SDK for python insert

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I am trying to find code examples on how G Suite is dealing with api calls in python. For example there is a method called insert: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert#try-it which permits you to create new users under your enterprise.

The point is that they dont have an example on how you can do that and i find a bit difficult to figure it out through their documentation. Are there any know examples that i could consult?

Comment: There is a python [quickstart in G Suite Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python). For example you are going to make request to the Directory API, you can use the code provided and just follow the steps there. Also, github provided some sample that you can use, you can visit [this link](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples).

Comment: Thanks for the input, i ve tried the quickstart guide and it worked like a treat but given my lvl of knowledge, i'm having a bit of hard time to figure out how to call the methods without an example. I would appreciate an example please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me, also using the QuickStart guide.

First, build your user object with the minimum required fields.

Note, this is just a dictionary containing a basic representation of a user object.

The minimum fields to use look like this:

```
user = {"name": {"familyName": "Burton", "givenName": "Haniel",}, "password": "some_pass", "primaryEmail": "haniel@yourgsuitedomain.com",}
```

You can add or update additional fields like any other dictionary:

```
 user["orgUnitPath"] = "/Imported"
```

Then, call the insert method like this in your main() program:

```
    result = service.users().insert(body=user).execute()
```

Result should be a JSON representation returned by the Directory API with additional attributes that are automatically added by Google.

Some additional links in case anyone else finds it useful:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.users.html

I'm working on building a small script/app to handle user creation, updates, and password resets to automate provisioning from our student information system. Depending on how it goes I might post to GitHub and add links here to save others time.